# Setting EditorFor value in razor

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have dropdownlist

```
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.grpid, "grpid", new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("grpid", String.Empty)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.grpid)
        </div>
    </div>
```

and editorfor textbox in a razor view.

```
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.code, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2"})
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.code, new { @id = "codeid" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.code)
        </div>
    </div>
```

When user select something from dropdown, i need to put selected data into textbox. 
I tried with jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('select#grpid').change(function () {
            var gr = $('#grpid').val()
            $('codeid input').val(gr)

        })
    });
</script>
```

but nothing  happened. When i "alert(gr)" popup shows with right value, but i can't get it into textbox.

can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked the selector for the text input is correct? It looks like it should be `#codeid` because you've said said `@id="codeid"` & you probably don't need the `input` part, but that depends on what html your `editorfor` generates

Comment: editorfor generate "<input class="text-box single-line" id="code" name="code" type="text" value="" />"
i tried to change codeid to code in jquery, but still nothing.